# Flex Cairngorm Spring Blazeds - Remoting Error - help me please

Tags: apache-flex, spring, remoting, blazeds, cairngorm

I seem to be getting the following error when I try to access a Remote Java class (on Spring/BlazeDS) from the Flex/Cairngorm application. I am going crazy at the moment trying to see what is wrong - any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks Mike.

```
**Error: C0007E: RemoteObject not found for mycomponentsService
    at RemoteObjects/getService()
    at com.adobe.cairngorm.business::ServiceLocator/getRemoteObject()
    at com.nomura.dashboard.client.business::DashBoardDelegate()**
```

All my config files are below:

**Cairngorm - BusinessDelegate.as**

```
this.service = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getRemoteObject("**mycomponentsService**");
```

**Cairngorm - Services.mxml**

```
mx:RemoteObject id="mycomponentsService" 
                destination="remotecomponentService" 
                showBusyCursor="true">
```

**Spring/BlazeDS - application-config.xml**

```
flex:remote-service ref="remotecomponentService" 

bean id="remotecomponentService" 
     class="com.mycompany.dashboard.server.dao.ComponentsDAO"
```

**Spring/BlazeDS - services-config.xml**

```
channel-definition id="myamf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel"
endpoint url="http://localhost:8080/dashboard-server/spring/messagebroker/amf" 
class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"
```

The web.xml also contains Spring references - see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4">

<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
<display-name>dashboard-server</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map /spring/* requests to the DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Does your `BusinessDelegate.as` really look like `"**mycomponentsService**"`, with the stars in it?  Or was that an attempt at formatting?

Comment: Hi Stu, that is formatting acutally - I think the bold feature of the website gone wrong - the name is mycomponentsService

Comment: @Michael: You can edit your Question, just as I have.  :)  It is the "Stack Overflow" way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your web.xml also please?  I am surprised to see the word *"spring"* in the endpoint URL.  My endpoints have always looked like

```
url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf"
```

E.g.: I think your services-config.xml should look more like this.

```
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
         <endpoint url="http://{server.name}/dashboard-server/messagebroker/amf"
                   class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/> 
    </channel-definition>
```

I would also suggest not hardcoding the end-point URL so much.  Just go with

```
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"
          url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" /> 
    </channel-definition>
```

---

## Update:

OK, so your web.xml looks OK, as does having the `spring` in your URL.  What I don's see in your Spring configuration file (`application-config.xml`) is the Spring URL mapping.  For example, in my Spring config files, in addition to the the bean definitions, there is a mapping.  E.g.:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /histogram/**=bean.HistogramController
            /counter/**=bean.CounterController
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bean.HistogramController" class="ch.comp.app.HistogramXportController"  />
<bean id="bean.CounterController"   class="ch.comp.app.CounterXportController"    />
```

*(I have one app that is Spring-based, and another that uses BlazeDS, but not both...so I might be missing something.  That said, what I'm asking still should be valid.  In theory.  But take it with a grain of salt.)*

Maybe some some super basic debugging is in order.  Can you check to see if the calls to your server are returning `HTTP 404` or not on theses problem endpoints?  A couple ways to do this:

- Check the access logs for `GET /dashboard-server/spring/messagebroker/amf`.  What is the HTTP status code for these requests? *(Free, easy, no new tools.)*
- If you are using FireFox as a browser, add the **[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)** plug in.  You don't have to tamper with the data, but it shows you what is being called, what is returned, and all the HTTP headers.
- Use a full on Flash/Flex oriented protocol sniffer tool, like **[Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)**.

It will very helpful to narrow down the problem to know if where these requests are failing on the communications stack.

Comment: Hi Stu, due to limited space in the comments I have answered my question...please see next answer

Comment: Also, how does the {server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/ - get set then?

Comment: It is auto-magic!  The server knows its name, knows its port, and knows what webapp it is running.  It replaces the `{parameter-name}` with the real, actual, running values.

Comment: Stu- it appears that i did not include the Cairngorm Services object in the main application to instantiate it - like <services/>

Once I did that it all worked fine. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached web.xml below. In terms of the word "Spring" - I am using the standard BlazrDS/Spring integration WAR file which requires "spring" to be there. The bean id="remotecomponentService" is acutally a Spring bean.

Are you saying even with the BlazeDS/Spring WAR I can use your solution above?

The web.xml also contains Spring references - see below

```
<web-app version="2.4">
<display-name>dashboard-server</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- Map /spring/* requests to the DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @Michael: Please put your web.xml in the question itself.  The Stack Overflow system does not function well as a threaded messaging platform because answers do not appear in a chronological order.  E.g.: For me, this 'answer' appeared above my own, so out conversational' is all mixed up.  (This is by design.)

Comment: Added web.xml to main question.

Comment: Cool.  You can delete this answer then :)